# Jupyter notebook command fails on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, firefox, jupyter

I have been using Jupyter notebooks for sometime now with no problems. My system set is:

- Windows 10
- Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
- FireFox

I have the following Jupyter components installed:

- `jupyter 1.0.0`
- `jupyter-client 5.2.3`
- `jupyter-console 5.2.0`
- `jupyter-core 4.4.0`

When I tried to execute `jupyter notebook` earlier today from the cmd window prompt I got the following errors messages:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Python36\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 45, in <module>
    ioloop.install()
  File "c:\python36\lib\site-packages\zmq\eventloop\ioloop.py", line 210, in install
    assert (not ioloop.IOLoop.initialized()) or \
AttributeError: type object 'IOLoop' has no attribute 'initialized'
```

I uninstalled Jupyter and reinstalled it and I get the same errors!

Why I am no longer able to execute `jupyter notebook` and how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out to me by another (SB) that the following might solve my problem:

```
C:\Python36>python -m pip install --upgrade pyzmq notebook
```

and it did!